# Windows service Null ReferenceException

Tags: windows, windows-services

I built a windows service on my local machine.  when I install and run it locally it works perfectly fine.  When I try to move it to my production machine I get a null reference exception error.

I've created an installation package that also works perfectly fine on my machine, but when i run it on the production machine the service still fails.

The service references a .dll that in turn has references to 3 other dlls.  when i build the project it pulls all of the dlls into the debug folder for the project... I've even installed the service from that folder and it works localy on my machine.

I know this has to have something to do with the references, but this is beyond me.  Any tips/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Really, this needn't be anything to do with the references.  Are you sure you're not hardcoding in (say) a folder path that doesn't exist on the server?  Or any other resource? 
Posting a stacktrace would help.

Comment: Thats IT! i realized after you said that that i was inheriting from a class that is in a web app itself... its pulling in an xml config file from its relative location IN THE WEB APP! /facepalm

Comment: the xml parser that the web app uses is also used in my service to get the db connection string from the config file which is in the web app structure... its in a try catch so if it fails to get it from the relative location in the web app it will go to the absolute location which in the companies old server was C:\... on this server all the web apps are stored on the E:\... i changed the c to e in the absolute reference and poof... it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take a look at the comments you'll see what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the machine you are installing it has the same machine has the same .dll your expecting installed.  For example if you are using .NET, and wrote the service in 3.5 and the target machine only has 2.0 that could be an issue, especially if the installer didn't try to install it.

Comment: I made sure that as one of the dependances for the service that 3.0 was installed... the server that this is going to also houses 4 - 5 other web apps that are written in anything from 2 - 3.5.